# Convert server default time to user's timezone unknown in advance using dayjs?

Tags: vue.js, dayjs

How do I convert server's default timezone to the user's local time?

```
date(){
  const date = dayjs(this.status.date);//returns string with time server, for example 2021-02-26 05:40:29
  return date.hour() === 0 && date.minute() === 0 ? date.format('DD.MM.YYYY') : date.format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm');

}
```

Comment: You dont need to worry about user's timezone. JS date object use local system's time to parse and show the dates in browser. So all you need to do is parse the server data properly. i.e., console.log(Date.parse(this.status.date));

Comment: But the catch is, the server date should be in UTC format

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that without using `dayjs` or additional library by using `new Date(your date)`. It will automatically convert the date to user local timezone.